# PHP - Display multiple csv file table from stored in local folder one at a time

Tags: php, csv

I have stored CSV files in a local folder. And i am displaying the names of the files in the local folder in the form of a list on the frontend dynamically.

FILE NAME LISTING

```
$path = "uploads/";
$files = scandir($path);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file[0] != '.') $nothidden[] = $file;
}

for ($x=0;$x<count($nothidden);$x++){
    ?><li class="active"><a><?php ${'file'.$x} = $nothidden[$x]; echo $nothidden[$x]; ?></a></li><br/>
    <?php
}
```

I am able to display the csv file in tabular form one at a time statically.

CSV FILE TABLE

```
$value = 'file.csv';
$target='uploads/'.basename($value);
echo "<table id='toggle-vis'>\n\n";
  $f = fopen($target, "r");
  while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                 echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
  }
  fclose($f);
  echo "\n</table>"
```

What i want is to display is the table of a csv file from the local directory when clicked on the particular name of the file in the list displayed. And when the other file name on the list is clicked, the previous table should be removed and the data from the clicked file should populate the table. 
Any help please?

Comment: You will need to use ajax to send the request and php to process the request, read the file and return the data from the csv file

Comment: you mean to say to clicking on csv it will list contents of csv right

Comment: @RamRaider could you explain how exactly to do that, i tried some code with it, but ultimately i was getting stuck.

Comment: @Dipakchavda yes, clicking on the csv file name listed.

Comment: If you post the code you tried and explain where you "got stuck" then we can have a look at it and suggest possibilities

Comment: @ApurvAnand You must call ajax request by click on csv file name from a list and in PHP it will process and return whole csv response.

Comment: @RamRaider what i am getting stuck with is, how to pass the filename as a variable, when clicked on the dynamically generated list name of that file.Apologies if i am not clear enough, this is my first question here.

Comment: @ApurvAnand I tried to post some code which may help to read csv and get back csv data now further process you should do yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very quickly written example - it works for me as a test but you will need to look at it carefully to make suitable edits to suit your final needs and environment.

The ajax function is invoked when an `a` within the list is clicked. The code looks at the `event` and uses the `event.target` to intercept the `innerHTML` for the `a` - that is the filename sent as a parameter ( via ajax ) to the php script. The PHP script checks that the method is `POST` and that there is a filename in the POST array - if it is OK then will process that file and send back the csv data. This could be edited so that only the filename rather than the full filepath is sent so that users do not know the actual filepaths used on your system!

```
<?php
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['filename'] ) ){

            $filename=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'filename', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

            if( $filename && realpath( $filename ) ){
                ob_clean();

                $hndl=fopen( $filename, 'r' );
                $html=array();

                $html[]="<table id='toggle-vis'>";
                while ( ( $line = fgetcsv( $hndl ) ) !== false ){
                    $html[]="<tr>";
                    foreach( $line as $cell )$html[]="<td>$cell</td>";
                    $html[]="</tr>";
                }
                $html[]="</table>";

                fclose( $hndl );

                header( 'Content-Type: text/html' );
                exit( implode( PHP_EOL, $html ) );
            }
        }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>csv manipulations</title>
        <script>
            /*
                basic ajax function
            */
            function ajax(m,u,p,c,o){
                /*
                    Method,Url,Params,Callback,Options
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call( this, xhr.response, o, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push( n+'='+p[ n ] );

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break;
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }

            /*
                event handler assigned to each `a` within the list ( li.active > a )
            */
            function getcsvdata(e){
                try{
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var method='post';
                    var url=location.href;
                    var params={
                        filename:e.target.innerHTML
                    };
                    var callback=csvcallback;
                    var options={};

                    ajax.call( this, method, url, params, callback, options );

                }catch( err ){
                    console.warn( err );
                }
            }

            /*
                ajax callback to process the response from the php script at the top
            */
            function csvcallback( data ){
                try{

                    var table=document.getElementById('toggle-vis');
                    if( table ){
                        var parent=table.parentNode;
                        parent.removeChild( table );

                        parent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',data);
                    }
                }catch( err ){
                    console.warn( err );
                }
            }


            /*
                Bind event handlers to each `a` in list 
            */
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                var col=Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('li.active > a') );
                col.forEach(function(e){
                    e.addEventListener('click',getcsvdata,false);
                });
            }, false );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CSV Files</h1>
        <ul id='list'>
        <?php

            /* edit to suit */
            $dir='c:/temp2/csvfiles';


            $col=glob( $dir . '/*.csv' );
            if( !empty( $col ) ){
                foreach( $col as $file ){
                    echo "<li class='active'><a href='#'>$file</a></li>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </ul>
        <table id='toggle-vis'>
            <tr>
                <td>csv data to appear here when links clicked</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you, my sir are Houdini. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Following the piece of code may help to you.

```
var csvData;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnGET").click(function() {
        csvData = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<csv file path>",
            dataType: "text/csv",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                alert("done!"+ csvData.getAllResponseHeaders())
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it'll be of great help.